# How to use a regex to get a particular part of a string

Tags: ruby, regex, sinatra

I'm creating a Sinatra-based application, and  am trying to parse a long string using regex to pull out a link from it.

Here's an excerpt of the string with the relevant information that I need to extract:

```
time=18ms\n[INFO] Calculating CPD for 0 files\n[INFO] CPD calculation finished\n[INFO] Analysis report generated in 325ms, dir size=14 KB\n[INFO] Analysis reports compressed in 187ms, zip size=8 KB\n[INFO] Analysis report uploaded in 31ms\n[INFO] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://sonar.company.com/dashboard/index/com.company.paas.maventestproject:MavenTestProject\n[INFO] Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report\n[INFO] More about the report processing at http://sonar.company.com/api/ce/task?id=AVhFxTkyob-dgWZqnfIn\n[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to be able to pull the following:

```
http://sonar.company.com/api/ce/task?id=AVhFxTkyob-dgWZqnfIn
```

The closest I got was with `/(?=http).[a*-z]*/` but that's not close to what I need as it found 615 matches instead of 1.

The problem also is that the id `AVhFxTkyob-dgWZqnfIn` is not static,  changing per build.

I've been using [Rubular.com](http://rubular.com) to find the proper regex I need to use.

Comment: This any good: `/http:\/\/\S+/`? See [here](http://www.rubular.com/r/aHG7BZZAmw) for demo.

Comment: Instead of loading a whole file in a string, read it line by line. In this way, you can quickly discard lines that don't start with `[INFO]`. Then check the line with `\bhttp://\S*` and parse the url.

Comment: You need to state the rules for identifying the string you wish to extract. In your example you show the string you want but don't tell us *why* it's that particular string. It's like saying you have an array of numbers `[3,5,8,12,13,20]` and want to know how to select `[3,5,13]`. Is it because they are odd numbers, prime numbers or something else? You need to begin your question with a statement of the problem, then present an example when appropriate. When you edit to clarify, please don't add "EDIT:". Lastly, in future, please boil your examples down to the bare essentials.

Comment: Thanks for the information, well the link is needed because it contains a json which has information that I'm going to need to pull out from that particular json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>> string = '[your long string here]'
>> regex = /(http:[\w\/.?=-]+)(\\n)/
>> string.scan(regex).first.first
=> "http://sonar.company.com/api/ce/task?id=AVhFxTkyob-dgWZqnfIn"
```

Following the example above, I ended up modifying the regex to the following:

```
(http:\/\/sonar[\w\/.?=-]+task[\w\/.?=-]+(?!.\\n))
```

.. and return it like this:

```
string.scan(regex).first.first
```

The reason why I modified the regex is because the previous regex, ended up with a lot of results when plugging in the full string rather than the excerpt that's in the OP.

Comment: This almost works (since the string also contains links before it's also matching them too).. I modified it to look like this `/(http:\/\/sonar[\w\/.?=-]+)(\\n)/` but that's matching another link also (which is in `******** -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonar.covisintrnd.com\n[INFO]`).. Anyway to tell it that it must contain something like `task` or `id=` or something similar?

Comment: Hmm, weird.. When I tried it on my app, it gave me the following error: `ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method 'first' for nil:NilClass` I'm guessing it's not returning anything therefore it's nil..

Comment: This regex worked (on rubular.com): `(http:\/\/sonar[\w\/.?=-]+)task[\w\/.?=-]+(?!.\\n)` but now it's actually returning (in the actual ruby app):  `[["http://sonar.company.com/api/ce/"]]`... hmm

Comment: Okay so it was a grouping problem, this works for me! `(http:\/\/sonar[\w\/.?=-]+task[\w\/.?=-]+(?!.\\n))`

Comment: So long as the words `sonar` and `task` will reliably be present, that looks like a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are well-tested tools that'll make your task easier. I'd recommend using URI's `extract` method:

```
require 'uri'

str = "time=18ms\n[INFO] Calculating CPD for 0 files\n[INFO] CPD calculation finished\n[INFO] Analysis report generated in 325ms, dir size=14 KB\n[INFO] Analysis reports compressed in 187ms, zip size=8 KB\n[INFO] Analysis report uploaded in 31ms\n[INFO] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://sonar.company.com/dashboard/index/com.company.paas.maventestproject:MavenTestProject\n[INFO] Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report\n[INFO] More about the report processing at http://sonar.company.com/api/ce/task?id=AVhFxTkyob-dgWZqnfIn\n[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------"

URI.extract(str)
# => ["http://sonar.company.com/dashboard/index/com.company.paas.maventestproject:MavenTestProject",
#     "http://sonar.company.com/api/ce/task?id=AVhFxTkyob-dgWZqnfIn"]
```

Then it's a simple matter of finding the link you want and working with it.

You'll also want to pay attention to all the other methods that URI brings to the party as it understands how to tear apart and build URIs according to the RFCs.

Don't roll your own code or regex to do what someone else has done, especially when that code is well tested. You'll avoid pitfalls that others will fall into. The authors/maintainers of URI manage the built-in pattern so we don't have to. And, it's a lot more sophisticated than you'd imagine to meet the RFC, such as:

```
URI::REGEXP::PATTERN::ABS_URI
"[a-zA-Z][\\-+.a-zA-Z\\d]*:(?:(?://(?:(?:(?:[\\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\\d;:&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\\d]{2})*@)?(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\\-.]|%\\h\\h)+|\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\[(?:(?:[a-fA-F\\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\\d]{1,4}|\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})|(?:(?:[a-fA-F\\d]{1,4}:)*[a-fA-F\\d]{1,4})?::(?:(?:[a-fA-F\\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\\d]{1,4}|\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}))?)\\])(?::\\d*)?|(?:[\\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\\d$,;:@&=+]|%[a-fA-F\\d]{2})+)(?:/(?:[\\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\\d]{2})*)*(?:/(?:[\\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\\d]{2})*)*)*)?|/(?:[\\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\\d]{2})*)*(?:/(?:[\\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\\d]{2})*)*)*)(?:\\?(?:(?:[\\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\\d;/?:@&=+$,\\[\\]]|%[a-fA-F\\d]{2})*))?|(?:[\\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\\d;?:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\\d]{2})(?:[\\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\\d;/?:@&=+$,\\[\\]]|%[a-fA-F\\d]{2})*)"
```